# Proving $\{a\}$ is a also set given that $a$ is a set. Introduction to Set Theory.

Tags: set-theory

So I have just started learning about set theory and I have this proposition after introducing two axioms.

*Axiom 1:* Axiom of extensionality: Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements.

*Axiom 2:* Axiom of pairs: If $a$ and $b$ are sets then so is $\{a,b\}.$

The proposition is that $\{a\}$ is also a set given that $a$ is a set.

*Given proof:* By axiom $2$, $\{a,a\}$ is a set. By axiom $1$, this is equal to $\{a\}$. QED.

However whilst reading this proof I had a doubt.

To use axiom $1$ in the proof, we need to assume $\{a\}$ is a set right? I think this because it literally says **two sets** are equal if and only if elements are the same and thus for this axiom to be applicable to need a 'priori' that $\{a\}$ is a set? If that is the case are we not in a circular argument?

Comment: It's not circular and youre not assuming that {a} is a set you're using the fact that a is a set

Comment: See axiom of pairs as: Given any sets $a, b$ there is a set $c$ such that $x \in c$ if, and only if, $x=a$ or $x=b$. Then, you have nothing to prove, if $a=b$ then the only element on the set $c$ ( the one that the axiom of pairs guarantees its existence) is $a$.

Comment: Since $a$ is a set, you know from the pairing axiom that $\{a,a\}$ is a set. Extensionality then tells you that $\{a\}$ is simply another name for the same set.

Comment: Think this way: $\{a,a\}$ is a set. The only element of this set is $a$, so there exists a set whose only element is $a$. After all, what matters in a set is what elements it contains, and nothing else. $\{a\}$ and $\{a,a\}$ are just notations.

Comment: Was there a previous axiom or explanation defining what a set is? e.g. about how a *set* is a collection of objects/elements written inside curly brackets and separated by a comma? If not, I actually agree with OP: I don't see how to get from $\{a,a\}$ is a set to $\{a,a\} = \{a\}$ *without* assuming that $\{a\}$ is a set. Because if nothing has told me that a set is a collection of objects written inside curly brackets and separated by a comma, then there is nothing to tell me that $\{a\}$ is a set.

Comment: I don't think there is a "circular argument" though. I just see that a *set* hasn't been defined as it should have been before these axioms were introduced.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson In axiomatic set theory there is no definition of a set. Sets are just objects which satisfy given axioms. For example, the axiom of pairing states that if $a$ and $b$ are sets then there exists a set whose elements are exactly $a$ and $b$. We usually denote this set by $\{a,b\}$. But this is just a notation, it isn't part of the axioms.

Comment: I see. Then surely the author could have written what you just wrote as the definition of the axiom of pairing, rather than use the notation with curly brackets? But it depends what level the book is aimed towards: maybe those reading the book are assumed to know all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to tie up some of the comments: The circularity you see here actually results from the extremely awful formulation "show $\{a\}$ is a set". Because, forgetting about set theory and just thinking logically, that is meaningless if we don't already know what $\{a\}$ is, and if we already know what it is we don't need to show it's a set.

That's the way people often phrase these things, but it's *informal* notation; the notation $\{\dots\}$ simply is not part of "official" set theory! When people say $\{a\}$ is a set they mean that there is a set with $a$ as its one and only element.

Or more formally, $$\exists s\left(\forall x\left(x\in s\iff x=a\right)\right).$$

Similarly, "$\{a,a\}$ is a set" means $$\exists s\left(\forall x\left(x\in s\iff x=a\lor x=a\right)\right).$$

Nothing circular about that, and it's clear the two are equivalent.

Comment: I think this hits the spot. One could complete this by saying that in the end, the exercise asks for a proof of $\forall a \, \exists s \, \forall x (x \in s \leftrightarrow x = a) $. (And also that $a = b$ can be defined as $\forall x (x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b)$ )