# Proving $\{a\}$ is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms

I recently came across the following post [Proving $\{a\}$ is a also set given that $a$ is a set. Introduction to Set Theory.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990439/proving-a-is-a-also-set-given-that-a-is-a-set-introduction-to-set-theor).
While I understand the answer given I am still unsure whether or not the proof given in the OP is correct, i.e. if it is legitimate to use the axiom of extensionality. It seems to me that the answer given only suggests that there is no need to use the axiom of extensionality, not that this is not permitted.
Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: How do you define $\{a\}$?

Comment: Ah! I see it now! The axiom of extensionality is what makes the notation $\{a\}$ well-defined. That is I need the axiom of extensionality to prove that there is *only* one set whose only element is $a$. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, yes, but that's not everything. You need to use the axiom of pairing too.

Comment: Axiom of pairing tells me that there is a set whose only element is $a$ and the axiom of extensionality tells me this set is unique. Do you mean that I need the axiom of pairing for uniqueness?

Comment: Are you satisfied by the linked proof that $\{ a \}$ is a set? If so, how you want to prove uniqueness? If $a=b$, then $\{ a \} = \{ b \}$?

Comment: By the axiom of pairing there is a set whose only element is $a$. Let $x,y$ be two such sets. Then by extensionality $x=y$. Hence we can define $\{a\}$ to be this set.

Comment: Correct. More specifically, Pairing axiom gives a pair-set for each $a,b$ and by Extensionality we prove that it is unique. Thus, we can "name" it **the** pair $\{ a,b \}$. Applying this to the pair $\{ a,a \}$, we define $\{ a \}= \{ a , a\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set can be defined in three ways:

1- By extension

2- By comprehension

3- By Venn diagram.

In your case $ \{a\} $ is a set defined by extension. it contains only one element which is $ a$.

In set Theory, same objects can be seen as sets or as elements.

$$\{a\} \text{ is an element of the set } \{\{a\}\}$$

Comment: Venn diagrams don't define sets.

Comment: Also in set theory **everything** is seen as a set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Every set is an element.

Comment: Yes, but that goes without saying.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am fan of Liverpool : You will never walk alone.